# React redux read .txt file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using React and Redux together.
I have an action file called **UploadFileAction.js** and here is the code:

```
export const selectFile = (file) => {
    return {
        type: 'FILE_SELECTED',
        payload: file
    }
};
```

The `file` parameter contain the uploaded file.

> What I want to do

I want to send the file content to my **reducer** not the whole file as a payload..

> What I have tried

```
let fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent){
    let textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
}
```

Now the `textFromFileLoaded` variable contain my file text but I couldn't pass it in my `payload`.

Comment: where are you dispatching this action and what is `file` you are sending? put more code plz

Comment: oh by the way. this is an asynchronous action, so you should return a promise which resolves on the filereader event "onload". You should look up how to hook up async calls with react-redux. Once again... docs:
https://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html

Comment: I am dispatching this action in my container file but you are right I need to hook up async calls..

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you asking to store the contents of a file someone uploads in like a string, then store that in your redux store to be accessed later via this.props.uploadedFileContents?

Comment: @GavinThomas exactly...
I have already made everything but I could not pass the file content in my `payload`

Comment: Yea this would ONLY work for like very few cases. Otherwise the data would be too large to store like this. Even though you may not want to hear this, I think you should be readingFile> sending file to external storage/database via dropbox/AWS/backend > storing the response (it's usually a string to find it again in their db) to the redux store for lookup and display later.

Comment: I totally agree with you but I just wanted to for learning and practice purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I am misunderstanding, but you have to dispatch the result of the action containing the file's text to pass it to the reducer. So it should look something like:

```
 let fileReader = new FileReader();
 fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent){
    dispatch(selectFile(fileLoadedEvent.target.result));
 } 
 fileReader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
```

further reading on this topic: https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html

Comment: i think that makes sense!

Comment: No I have already dispatched my action in my container all I want here is to pass my file content to my reducer

Comment: Oh I edited it. You need the onload defined before you readAsText(); Just another guess